# Find cubic equation given four points?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am working on finding the area of a solid object. I have 4 points that I need to calculate a cubic equation from. I have tried relentlessly but to no avail I always get the wrong answer.

The four points are;(0,2.7) (0.5, 2.9) (1,3.2) (1.9, 3.4)

Using excel, the formula should be; 
-0.24728x^3 + 0.57093x^2 + 0.17636x + 2.7

If anyone can provide working out on how you got the equation it would be much obliged! No matrices please just substitution.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are given four pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ and you are told $f(x_i)=y_i$ for each pair. So just suppose that $$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
Then substitute each pair of numbers into this equation to get four equations in the four unknowns $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Solve the system of equations for these four unknowns and you should get $a=-0.24728$, $b=0.57093$, $c=0.17636$, and $d=2.7$, approximately.

For example, when you substitute the first pair, you get
$$2.7=d$$
which is especially nice. I would immediately replace $d$ with $2.7$ in the remaining three equations to get a system of three equations in three unknowns $a$, $b$, and $c$ to solve (now you already have $d$). When you substitute the second pair, and the known value of $ d $, you get
$$2.9=(0.5)^3a +(0.5)^2b+0.5c+2.7$$
which can be rewritten as
$$0.125a+0.25b+0.5c=0.2$$
and so on.

I suppose you could use this equation to write one of the variable in terms of the remaining two, such as $$c=0.4-0.25a-0.5b.$$

Can you take it from here? Do you need help solving the system of equations?

Comment: God I honestly must be so bad at Maths. I am forcing myself to get better I want to learn. Every time I start it off such as this and I always get the wrong answer. Just tried it and my a value was; -0.11560? Could you please elaborate even further (so sorry im terrible at maths).

Comment: how did you get 0.125a + 0.25b + 0.5c = 0.7 There is no way it can equal 0.7 as you go 2.9 -2.7 = 0.2

Comment: nvm just did it thank you very much!

Comment: You're right, I have a typo. I will replace the $0.7$ with $0.2$. Note that also changes the constant term in the next equation (fixed that too). Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

To explain a little what is going on, if we have distinct points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)$ then the cubic polynomial $$f_1(x)=(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$$ is equal to zero when $x=x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $f_1(x_1)=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)$

so if we look at $$g_1(x)=\frac {f_1(x)}{f_1(x_1)}=\frac {(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)}$$ we find (by construction) that $g_1(x)=0$ for $x=x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $g_1(x_1)=\frac {f_1(x_1)}{f_1(x_1)}=1$

Our polynomial is then (with the other $g_i(x)$ constructed similarly) $$L(x)=y_1g_1(x)+y_2g_2(x)+y_3g_3(x)+y_4g_4(x)$$

Since the $g_i$ are cubic $L(x)$ is at most cubic.

[This construction - Lagrange Interpolation - always reminds me of the Chinese Remainder Therorem]